# Unable to import nonsense from Nostril

Tags: python

I am trying to import nonsense from Nostril (
`from nostril import nonsense`)
but I get this error;

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [12], line 1
----> 1 from nostril import nonsense

ImportError: cannot import name 'nonsense' from 'nostril' (c:\Users\GithuaG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nostril\__init__.py)
```

Here is what the **init**.py file contains:

```
 from .__version__ import __version__, __title__, __url__, __description__
from .__version__ import __author__, __email__
from .__version__ import __license__, __copyright__

from .ng import NGramData
from .nonsense_detector import (
    nonsense, generate_nonsense_detector, test_unlabeled, test_labeled,
    ngrams, dataset_from_pickle, sanitize_string
)
```

Tried researching on the web but no success.
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You most probably did `pip install nostril` before you installed the actual nostril package that you needed (just like I did). This would have caused another package that is used for testing to be installed alongside. You can either uninstall both nostril packages and then re-install just the nostril package you need.

Or you can directly import the nonsense object from nonsense_detector as below if you need both the packages

```
from nostril.nonsense_detector import nonsense
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

*had to install the git repo directly, and then import the main two functions (ng, nonsense_detector)

Also, pro tip, the string you run this on has to be at least 6 characters. you'll get a min_length error if less than 6.

```
# !pip install git+https://github.com/casics/nostril.git
from nostril import ng
from nostril import nonsense_detector as nd

def is_nonsense_text(text):
    if nd.nonsense(text):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
    
df['nonsense_email_handle'] = df['email_handle'].apply(is_nonsense_text)
```